# What was that show-- 1980s or 1990s anthology horror/sci fi episode

Tags: story-identification, tv, episode-identification

It wasn't Monsters ... What was it??' An anthology tv sci-fi/horror episode with a man "ill," maybe restrained,  in a bed at a rustic home acting feral while his family and a visiting doctor hover about him, concerned. The doc asks how he's doing. The wife seems concerned about his illness; but the audience is freaked that he's going to jump out of bed and attack someone. Then there's a twist... Probably.... I had to leave & never learned what happened. Anyone know the show/episode??!! It's bugged me off & on for years!! Thx.

Comment: There were several anthology series like that in the eighties and nineties. Tales from the Crypt? The Outer Limits?

Comment: This is awful! Now I HAVE to know how it ended :D

Comment: What about Tales from the Dark Side?  That show used the scare the bejeebers out of me!

Answer (score 2):

Night Gallery had a scene very much like that in 1972's production of *The Caterpillar*.
A man plots to kill the older husband of a young, beautiful woman at a remote outpost in British-occupied Borneo. The plan misfires, and he finds himself is bound to a bed, half insane from the pain of the earwig burrowing through his brain, tended by the couple. And, yes, there is a horrifying & memorable twist at the end.